# Want to understand why is this same code producing a different output for someone else

Tags: c++, list

I have a code that I need to find its output:

```
int main()
{
    list<int> intList;
    ostream_iterator<int> screen(cout, " ");
    list<int>::iterator listIt;
    intList.push_back(5);
    intList.push_front(23);
    intList.push_front(45);
    intList.pop_back();
    intList.push_back(35);
    intList.push_front(0);
    intList.push_back(50);
    intList.push_front(34);
    copy(intList.begin(), intList.end(), screen);
    listIt = intList.begin();
    intList.insert(listIt, 76);
    ++listIt;
    ++listIt;
    intList.insert(listIt, 38);
    intList.pop_back();
    ++listIt;
    ++listIt;
    intList.erase(listIt);
    intList.push_front(2 * intList.back());
    intList.push_back(3 * intList.front());
    copy(intList.begin(), intList.end(), screen);
    cout << endl;

    cout << endl;
}
```

I get this output:

```
34 0 45 23 35 50 46 76 34 0 38 45 23 138
```

While someone else gets:

```
34 0 45 23 5 0 35 50
70 76 34 0 38 45 23 0 35 210
```

Which one is correct and why?

Comment: What did the person who got different out use?  I cannot replicate the second example on g++, clang or MSVS

Comment: There are a couple of numbers like 70,210 etc. which are not even a part of your program. Are you sure you both are using the same code? I don't think so.

Comment: Wild guess: Was the other person using something like `#define list vector`? Post a [MCVE] please.

Comment: [Here](http://ideone.com/mqbiDe) the result is your version.

Answer (score 2):

It takes two small changes to your code to get the second output:

```
#include <list>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    list<int> intList;
    ostream_iterator<int> screen(cout, " ");
    list<int>::iterator listIt;
    intList.push_back(5);
    intList.push_front(23);
    intList.push_front(45);
    intList.push_back(0);  // 1. You had intList.pop_back();
    intList.push_back(35);
    intList.push_front(0);
    intList.push_back(50);
    intList.push_front(34);
    copy(intList.begin(), intList.end(), screen);
    cout << endl;     // 2. Add an extra end-of-line
    listIt = intList.begin();
    intList.insert(listIt, 76);
    ++listIt;
    ++listIt;
    intList.insert(listIt, 38);
    intList.pop_back();
    ++listIt;
    ++listIt;
    intList.erase(listIt);
    intList.push_front(2 * intList.back());
    intList.push_back(3 * intList.front());
    copy(intList.begin(), intList.end(), screen);
    cout << endl;

    cout << endl;
}
```

Output:

```
34 0 45 23 5 0 35 50 
70 76 34 0 38 45 23 0 35 210
```

I suspect you are not both running exactly the same code...

Comment: Bravo! This is it(must be) :)

Comment: @anurag86 How was your question asking about _small changes_, that reproduce the 2nd behavior/output? Are you trolling us here?

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ : I didnt understand the context of your comment perhaps because you didnt understand how i appreciated atkins the way he reached this answer(which i couldnt have so easily)

Comment: Thank you so much! Now I can understand why they didn't get the same output...